# Can I make a regex array to iterate through in C++?

Tags: c++, array, regex

I have to check a string to various regular expressions in C++. Up to now, I've done this using something similar to this:

```
regex regex_a (".."); string rewrite_a = "($1/$2)";
regex regex_b (".."); string rewrite_b = "($1)";
regex regex_c (".."); string rewrite_c = "($2)";

if (regex_match(string, regex_a)) {
    cout << regex_replace(string, regex_a, rewrite_a);
} else if (regex_match(string, regex_b)) {
    cout << regex_replace(string, regex_b, rewrite_b);
} else if (regex_match(string, regex_c)) {
    cout << regex_replace(string, regex_c, rewrite_c);
}
```

Is this the cleanest way to do this? Isn't there a way to make a regex array and iterate through that? It would make the code much more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably like this:

C++11:

```
vector< pair<regex, string> > regex_pairs = { {regex(".."), "($1/$2)"}, {regex(".."), "($1)"}, {regex(".."), "($2)"} };
for(auto pa:regex_pairs){
    cout << regex_replace(string, pa.first, pa.second);
}
```

C++03:

```
vector< pair<regex, string> > regex_pairs;
regex_pairs.push_back(make_pair(regex(".."), "($1/$2)"));
regex_pairs.push_back(make_pair(regex(".."), "($1)"));
regex_pairs.push_back(make_pair(regex(".."), "($2)"));
for(vector< pair<regex, string> >::iterator it = regex_pairs.begin();it!=regex_pairs.end(); it++){
    cout << regex_replace(string, it->first, it->second);
}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Code Review! :) I'll hope you'll enjoy it. Notes about your answer: you can use a map instead of a vector of pairs and it's important to show how you would initialize `regex_pairs`.

Comment: Yes, I should have the code to initialize regex_pairs, and just fixed it. Thanks !
Also, as you said, one can also use map as you said, if one want to sort outputs by keys.

Comment: Note: With C++11, initialization can be nicer.

Comment: Definitely! I updated the answer. Thanks again !

Comment: One note: in C++11 you can also use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`, it constructs new elements directly in place instead of copying/moving:
http://enki-tech.blogspot.com/2012/08/c11-vector-improved-how-it-works.html
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back

Comment: Camil: Thanks ! I fixed another typo.(hopefully)

Comment: Matt: Thanks!! So, it can be like: regex_pairs.emplace_back(regex(".."), "($1/$2)") to avoid calling pair<,>'s copy constructor in C++11 (utilising  variadic template, argument forwarding, placement new).